# Combine multiple `python.withPackages` defintitions

Tags: nix

I have multiple `python.withPackages` expressions that I want to be able to automatically merge into a single `python` expression.

That is, given the following two definitions:

```
py1 = python37.withPackages selectPkgs1
py2 = python37.withPackages selectPkgs2
```

I want to provide some combinator, `merge`, such that

```
p3 = merge [py1, py2]
```

is the same derivation as

```
p3 = python37.withPackages (pkgs: (selectPkgs1 pkgs) ++ (selectPkgs2 pkgs))
```

I'd also be interested in solutions where I can build one output on top of the other. That is, performing the merge given `py1` and `selectPkgs2`. Trying

```
py3 = py1.withPackages selectPkgs2
```

seemed to make sense, but that is just the same as `py2`--the packages selected by `selectPkgs1` are lost.

Many `nix` language environments seem to share this `withPackages` construct, so I'm happy to hear answers in other languages. Thanks.

Comment: You'd need to make a PR to expose [`extraLibs`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/e50c67ad7eefa8e77436fbd0366b69638b1c8713/pkgs/development/interpreters/python/wrapper.nix#L15) in the `passthru` attributes. Then you'll want a function to make sure the python versions match and then combines them. You'd still be throwing away a lot of other details of one of the two python interpreters though. Such a function would be a leaky abstraction.

Comment: If they expose extraLibs, I imagine I'd be able to define this myself. Do you suppose they'd be open to a PR along the lines of redefining `withPackages` [gist](https://gist.github.com/trevorcook/9f50db71a05eda6dc94584a20be1a132)?

Comment: In my experience contributions like this are valued by the maintainers. The idea in the gist looks good. My previous comment was about the "algebraic" operation you suggested in the question here. It does not apply to your second idea of chaining `withPackages` attribute invocations. It seems like your gist can be used as an addition, but for the PR it makes more sense to make a potentially breaking change to keep the implementation and interface simple.

Comment: This is really great feedback. Thanks a lot.